# How to change the object of an animations scale when you saved the key frames as LocRotScale

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet

guys fairly new to blender and I ran into some trouble...

I worked really hard on an animation saving each keyframe via LocRotScale
However now I want to change the object size but I can't... Is there any way I could change LocRotScale to LocRot without losing anything else in my animation?

PS: in the image in the dope sheet panel, it says LocRot... that's because I tried to fix it because previously it said LocRotScale and I thought I could change it by getting rid of Scale in LocRotScale but It didn't work :(

[image]

Comment: In future, please don't just add random tags to your question, instead, read the tag descriptions and check that they are actually relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove separately the scale keys in the dopesheet.

[image]